# Use encfs with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, encryption

I'm trying to read from an encfs filesystem with JavaScript but don't get the correct use of it. I use the [CryptoJS](http://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/) library.

The .ecnfs6.xml with standard settings and password 123456:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<!DOCTYPE boost_serialization>
<boost_serialization signature="serialization::archive" version="9">
<cfg class_id="0" tracking_level="0" version="20">
  <version>20100713</version>
  <creator>EncFS 1.7.4</creator>
  <cipherAlg class_id="1" tracking_level="0" version="0">
    <name>ssl/aes</name>
    <major>3</major>
    <minor>0</minor>
  </cipherAlg>
  <nameAlg>
    <name>nameio/block</name>
    <major>3</major>
    <minor>0</minor>
  </nameAlg>
  <keySize>192</keySize>
  <blockSize>1024</blockSize>
  <uniqueIV>1</uniqueIV>
  <chainedNameIV>1</chainedNameIV>
  <externalIVChaining>0</externalIVChaining>
  <blockMACBytes>0</blockMACBytes>
  <blockMACRandBytes>0</blockMACRandBytes>
  <allowHoles>1</allowHoles>
  <encodedKeySize>44</encodedKeySize>
  <encodedKeyData>
A2MxizkB27kOot67DqX/ftXoAiO0P8ORF4BqbKnbMeHuIusJl5y36Qy8o8w=
  </encodedKeyData>
  <saltLen>20</saltLen>
  <saltData>
z59o4aHs2QaKGdoEMEigtqSkXyw=
  </saltData>
  <kdfIterations>97742</kdfIterations>
  <desiredKDFDuration>500</desiredKDFDuration>
</cfg>
</boost_serialization>
```

I created a file with name and content "test" and tried to decrypt that wit no success:

```
var data = "Q75cZB2ok,JdXDqvWh8HbwHI";  // filename
var key = "123456";
var salt = "z59o4aHs2QaKGdoEMEigtqSkXyw=";

data = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(data);
salt = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(salt);

var cipher = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(data, key, {keySize: 192/32});
```

Answer (score 4):

The way EncFS works is that it creates a volume key (192 bits according to your config) and encrypts the volume key using another key which is derived from the user's password (the algorithm used for deriving the password key is called PBKDF2 - Password-Based Key Derivation Function).

Given that config file, what you have to do is:

- Take the user's password, input into PBKDF2 computation along with the salt and iteration count (both present in the config file) to get back the password key.
- Using the password key, decrypt the volume key (AES stream decryption) from the encodedKeyData field of the config

Once you have the volume key you can use it to decrypt filenames as well as file contents.

For examples of how this is done, you can take a look at the following library which I wrote in Java:
https://github.com/mrpdaemon/encfs-java

Answer (score 2):

*Current JavaScript implementations are far too slow to generate a
PBKDF2 with more than `1000 - 2000` (not noticeably delayed) to
`10000` (noticeable delay) iterations. An iteration count like in your
example `97742` would take hours to finish...*

**Update**: Only when using CryptoJS apparently: [see JSPerf](http://jsperf.com/pbkdf2-sjcl-cryptojs) and [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joscha/rz6yu/) for PBKDF2.